# Best practice for making a custom query in a model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model named "Rate" and a related controller named "RateController".
if want to make a custom query in Rate model, we could use local scope or static function like these:

using static function in the Rate model:

```
public static function avgerage($type, $id)
{
    return static::where('rateble_type', $type)
                ->where('rateble_id', $id)
                ->avg('star');
}
```

using local scope in Rate model:

```
public function scopeAverageRate($type, $id, $query)
{
    return $query->where('rateble_type', $type)
                 ->where('rateble_id', $id)
                 ->avg('star');
}
```

and finally, we call one of the above methods in the controller.

The question is, which one is the best practice?
using a local scope or defining a static function in the model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use static methods if you need the query builder.
- Static methods are great for making complete queries and returning the results.

More information about [Static methods on Eloquent model](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/static-methods-on-eloquent-model) It will help.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate further, if you instantiate a `Model` and are using a `method` on it and don't care about the state of that particular instance, you should use static methods. The number of times this situation is actually applicable is pretty rare. Most of the time it will be non-static, so most of the time you'll be using `local scope`.

When creating a query, ask yourself does it relate to the **behavior** of the `Model`? If so, then use local scope. If it relates to the **concept** of the `Model`, then use static.

Answer (score 0):

Since controller should be only responsible for handling the request and sending the response, my suggestion is to avoid making them "fat" with query implementations (this is model layer responsibility).

I would do the following:

```
class MyModel 
{
     public function average($type, $id)
     {
         // query implementation
     }
}

class MyController 
{
    public function index($type, $id)
    {
        $model = new MyModel();
        $average = $model->average($type, $id);
        // return response
    }
}
```